# Is there a Ruby method to grab the ones/tenths/hundredths place for an integer?

Tags: ruby

I'm doing a Ruby kata that asks me to find the sum of the digits of all the numbers from 1 to N (both ends included).

So if I had these inputs, I would get these outputs:

```
For N = 10 the sum is 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+(1+0) = 46

For N = 11 the sum is 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+(1+0)+(1+1) = 48

For N = 12 the sum is 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+(1+0)+(1+1) +(1+2)= 51
```

Now I know in my head what needs to be done. Below is the code that I have to solve this problem:

```
def solution(n)
  if n <= 9
    return n if n == 1
    solution(n-1) + n
  elsif n >= 10
    45 + (10..n) #How can I grab the ones,tenths, and hundreds?
  end
end
```

Basically everything is fine until I hit over 10.

I'm trying to find some sort of method that could do this. I searched Fixnum and Integer but I haven't found anything that could help me. I want is to find something like `"string"[0]` but of course without having to turn the integer back in forth between a string and integer. I know that there is a mathematical relationship there but I'm having a hard time trying to decipher that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I do not know if it's possible to get the digit at index n of a number without doing some string conversion though. If you drop that requirement, you can just do `def f(n);(1..n).map{|x|x.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)}.reduce(:+);end`, so `f(10) == 46`, `f(11) == 48`, etc.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers is right. No direct method, need to put manual effort :(

Comment: The obvious answer is to use integer division by the power of 10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [modulo](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Fixnum.html#method-i-25) and integer [division](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Fixnum.html#method-i-2F) to calculate it recursively:

```
def sum_digits(n)
  return n if n < 10
  (n % 10) + sum_digits(n / 10)
end

sum_digits(123)
# => 6
```

Answer (score 5):

A beginner would probably do this:

```
123.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i)
# => [1, 2, 3]
```

but a more thoughtful person would do this:

```
n, a = 123, []
until n.zero?
  n, r = n.divmod(10)
  a.unshift(r)
end
a
# => [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: "...without having to turn the integer back in forth between a string and integer..."

Answer (score 2):

Rather than computing the sum of the digits for each number in the range, and then summing those subtotals, I have computed the total using combinatorial methods. As such, it is much more efficient than straight enumeration.

**Code**

```
SUM_ONES = 10.times.with_object([]) { |i,a| a << i*(i+1)/2 }
S = SUM_ONES[9]

def sum_digits_nbrs_up_to(n)
  pwr = n.to_s.size - 1
  tot = n.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)
  sum_leading_digits = 0
  pwr.downto(0).each do |p|
    pwr_term = 10**p
    leading_digit = n/pwr_term
    range_size = leading_digit * pwr_term
    tot += sum_leading_digits * range_size +
           sum_digits_to_pwr(leading_digit, p)
    sum_leading_digits += leading_digit
    n -= range_size
  end
  tot
end  

def sum_digits_to_pwr(d, p)
  case
  when d.zero? && p.zero?
    0
  when d.zero?
    10**(p-1) * S * d * p
  when p.zero?
    10**p * SUM_ONES[d-1]
  else
    10**p * SUM_ONES[d-1] + 10**(p-1) * S * d * p
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
sum_digits_nbrs_up_to(456)   #=>   4809
sum_digits_nbrs_up_to(2345)  #=>  32109
sum_digits_nbrs_up_to(43021) #=> 835759
sum_digits_nbrs_up_to(65827359463206357924639357824065821)
                             #=> 10243650329265398180347270847360769369
```

These calculations were all essentially instantaneous.  I verified the totals for the first three examples by straight enumeration, using @sawa's method for calculating the sum of digits for each number in the range.

**Explanation**

The algorithm can best be explained with an example.  Suppose `n` equals `2345`.

We begin by defining the following functions:

- `t(n)`  : sum of all digits of all numbers between `1` and `n`, inclusive (the answer)
- `sum(d)`: sum of all digits between `1` and `d`, inclusive, (for `d=1..9, sum(d) = 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45`).
- `g(i)`  : sum of digits of the number `i`.
- `f(i,j)`: sum of all digits of all integers between `i` and `j-1`, inclusive.
- `g(m)`  : sum of digits of the number `m`.
- `h(d,p)`: sum of all digits of all numbers between `0` and `d*(10^p)-1` (derived below).

Then (I explain the following below):

```
t(2345) = f(0-1999)+f(2000-2299)+f(2300-2339)+f(2340-2344)+g(2345)

f(   0-1999) =                           h(2,3) =       h(2,3)
f(2000-2299) = 2       * (2299-2000+1) + h(3,2) = 600 + h(3,2)
f(2300-2339) = (2+3)   * (2339-2300+1) + h(4,1) = 200 + h(4,1)
f(2340-2344) = (2+3+4) * (2344-2340+1) + h(5,0) =  45 + h(5,0)
g(2345)      = 2+3+4+5                          =  14
```

so

```
t(2345) = 859 + h(2,3) + h(3,2) + h(4,1) + h(5,0)
```

First consider `f(2000-2299)`.  The first digit, `2`, appears in every number in the range `(2000..2299)`; i.e., `300` times.  The remaining three digits contribute (by definition) `h(3,2)` to the total:

```
f(2000-2299) = 2 * 300 + h(3,2)
```

For `f(2300-2339)` the first two digits, `2` and `3`, are present in all `40` numbers in the range `(2300..2339)` and the remaining two digits contribute `h(4,1)` to the total:

```
f(2300-2339) = 5 * 40 + h(4,1)
```

For `f(2340-2344)`, the first three digits, '2`,`3`and`4``` , are present in all four number in the range ``(2340-2344) ``` and the last digit contributes `h(5,0)` to the total.

It remains to derive an expression for computing `h(d,p)`.  Again, this is best explained with an example.

Consider `h(3,2)`, which is the sum of the all digits of all numbers between `0` and `299`.

First consider the sum of digits for the first digit. `0`, `1` and `2` are each the first digit for 100 numbers in the range `0-299`.  Hence, the first digit, summed, contributes

```
0*100 + 1*100 + 2*100 = sum(2) * 10^2
```

to the total.  We now add the sum of digits for the remaining `2` digits.  The `300` numbers each have `2` digits in the last two positions.  Each of the digits `0-9` appears in `1/10th` of `2 * 300 = 600` digits; i.e, `60` times.  Hence, the sum of all digits in last `2` digit positions, over all `300` numbers, equals:

```
sum(9) * 2 * 300 / 10 = 45 * 2 * 30 = 2700.
```

More generally,

```
h(d,p) = sum(d-1) * 10**p + sum(9) * d * p * 10**(p-1) if d >  0 and p >  0
       = sum(d-1) * 10**p                              if d >  0 and p == 0
       =                    sum(9) * d * p * 10**(p-1) if d == 0 and p >  0
       = 0                                             if d == 0 and p == 0
```

Applying this to the above example, we have

```
h(2,3) = sum(1) * 10**3 + (45 * 2 * 3) * 10**2 =  1 * 1000 + 270 * 100 = 28000
h(3,2) = sum(2) * 10**2 + (45 * 3 * 2) * 10**1 =  3 *  100 + 270 *  10 =  3000
h(4,1) = sum(3) * 10**1 + (45 * 4 * 1) * 10**0 =  6 *   10 + 180 *   1 =   240
h(5,0) = sum(4) * 10**0                        = 10 *    1             =    10
```

Therefore

```
t(2345) = 859 + 28000 + 3000 + 240 + 10 = 32109
```

The code above implements this algorithm in a straightforward way.

I confirmed the results for the first three examples above by using using @sawa's code to determine the sum of the digits for each number in the range and then summed those totals:

```
def sum_digits(n)
  a = []
  until n.zero?
    n, r = n.divmod(10)
    a.unshift(r)
  end
  a.reduce(:+)
end

def check_sum_digits_nbrs_up_to(n)
  (1..n).reduce(0) {|t,i| t + sum_digits(i) }
end

check_sum_digits_nbrs_up_to(2345) #=> 32109
```